# In .vimrc, how to edit, save, and exit a file and then run a shell command?

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible to run a shell command on the shell prompt automatically right after editing, saving, and exiting a file whenever I edit a file with a certain extension?

In my .vimrc, I have the following (thanks to someone who posted this as an answer to someone else's question):

```
let shells = { 
        \     'py': "python",
        \    }

let extension = expand("%:e")

if has_key(shells,extension)
    let fileshell = shells[extension]
    let line = "#!" . system("which " . fileshell)

    0put = line

    if a:permission
        :autocmd BufWritePost * :autocmd VimLeave * :!chmod 755 %
    endif

endif

endfunction

:autocmd BufNewFile *.* :call Hashbang(1,1)
```

As I chmod the file inside a vi session, I want to run a .py file automatically right after exiting my vi session, for example:

```
# vi test.py
# ./test.py
```

Thank you for your advice in advance!

- Life Learner

Comment: This is the answer to the question you just deleted: `myhash1.select {|k,v| k.to_s.strip.empty? }.values #=> [ "no value", "empty" ]`. I will delete this message soon.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that from within Vim, but by writing a short shell script wrapper, e.g. `vimrun`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 "ERROR: No file passed!"
    exit 1
fi

vim "$1" && \
    if [ -x "$1" ]; then
        PATH=".:$PATH"
        exec "$1"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In default `bash` if you hit `CTRL-x` followed by `CTRL-e`, you get your `$EDITOR` opened against a temporary file.  Type anything in that file and save then quit.  Bash will run everything you typed in that file.

Comment: In general, you press whatever key sequence the `edit-and-execute-command` Readline function is bound to.